Computing the principal curvatures of the $n$-dimensional paraboloid.
Let $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be the $n$-dimensional paraboloid defined as the graph $f(x)=|x|^2$. How can I easily compute the principal curvatures of $M$? I have been able to compute the shape operator for a general graph (see here for example). Taking the case of the paraboloid, the matrix of the shape operator is given by
$$ {s^i}_j= \frac{2\delta^i_j}{(1+|\nabla f|^2)^{1/2}} - \frac{8x_ix_j}{(1+|\nabla f|^2)^{3/2}}. $$
I know that the principal curvatures should be the eigenvalues of this (symmetric) matrix, and they should form an orthonormal basis with respect to the induced metric. How can I compute this easily?

Do the case of a surface in $\Bbb R^3$ first. Do you know what the lines of curvature of a surface of revolution are? Meusnier’s formula will help you find the principal curvature of the parallels (which will become spheres in higher dimensions). See Section 2 of Chapter 2 of my (free) diff geo text, linked in my profile, if you need it.
